# fputcsv() doesn't escape double quotes?

Tags: php, csv

Consider this code:

```
$escapeChar = '"';

$source = fopen('E:/1.csv', 'r');
$row = fgetcsv($source, null, ',', '"', $escapeChar);
fclose($source);

$writeTo = fopen('E:/2.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($writeTo, $row, ',', '"', $escapeChar);
fclose($writeTo);

$read = fopen('E:/2.csv', 'r');
$row = fgetcsv($read, null, ',', '"', $escapeChar);

print_r($row);
```

With 1.csv like this:

```
"Affordable Dentist.""","Mon - Thu: 8:00 am - 5:00 pm Fri: 8:00 am - 1:00 pm Sat - Sun Closed\",,,"amex, cash, check, diners club, discover"
```

Run the code and it output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Affordable Dentist.",Mon - Thu: 8:00 am - 5:00 pm Fri: 8:00 am - 1:00 pm Sat - Sun Closed\"
    [1] =>
    [2] =>
    [3] => amex, cash, check, diners club, discover
)
```

Then change $escapeChar:

```
$escapeChar = '\\';
```

And run the code again which output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Affordable Dentist."
    [1] => Mon - Thu: 8:00 am - 5:00 pm Fri: 8:00 am - 1:00 pm Sat - Sun Closed\",,,amex
    [2] =>  cash
    [3] =>  check
    [4] =>  diners club
    [5] =>  discover"
)
```

It just seems whichever I use for the `$escapeChar`, `'\\'` or `'"'`, it's wrong.

The correct final result should be like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Affordable Dentist."
    [1] => Mon - Thu: 8:00 am - 5:00 pm Fri: 8:00 am - 1:00 pm Sat - Sun Closed\
    [2] =>
    [3] =>
    [4] => amex, cash, check, diners club, discover
)
```

How to make it right here so whatever CSV file read (**1.csv**) can be output correctly (**2.csv**) and then the output (**2.csv**) can again be parsed correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate a bit more on the answer from @murat-tutumlu the problem is because you're using the double quote character as both the escape character and the enclosure character parameters to `fgetcsv()` and `fputcsv()`. The steps when reading the first item are:

1. Read the item = `"Affordable Dentist."""`
2. Remove the enclosure character = `Affordable Dentist.""`
3. Process the escape character = `Affordable Dentist."`

When you switch to using the backslash character as the escape character for all operations then the second item escapes the ending enclosure character and breaks the parsing in a different way.

I would recommend using a different escape character in your source data if possible. If you can't change the data then you can change your code to use double quote as the escape character for the first call to `fgetcsv()` and then switch to an unused character for the subsequent calls.

```php
$escapeChar = '"';

$source = fopen('E:/1.csv', 'r');
$row = fgetcsv($source, null, ',', '"', $escapeChar);
fclose($source);

// Need to use a different escape character from here
$escapeChar = '^';

$writeTo = fopen('E:/2.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($writeTo, $row, ',', '"', $escapeChar);
fclose($writeTo);

$read = fopen('E:/2.csv', 'r');
$row = fgetcsv($read, null, ',', '"', $escapeChar);

print_r($row);
```

Comment: Why even use the escape character? If you have the backslash as an escape character it weirdly doesn't escape `\"` at all. I feel like the escapeCharater should be set to empty string to disable it altogether. ```php > $fp = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
php > fputcsv($fp, ['\"'], ',', '"', "");
"\"""
php > fputcsv($fp, ['\"']);
"\""```

Answer (score 2):

This proprietary escaping mechanism has been around for a long time, but since 7.4 you can switch this off:

> The escape_char parameter now also accepts an empty string to disable the proprietary escape mechanism.

This would be your new code:

```php
fputcsv($writeTo, $row, ',', '"', '');
//                                ^^ empty escape character
```

It will give the following output:

```
"Affordable Dentist.""","Mon - Thu: 8:00 am - 5:00 pm Fri: 8:00 am - 1:00 pm Sat - Sun Closed\",,,"amex, cash, check, diners club, discover"
```

### References

- [`fputcsv()` changelog](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php#refsect1-function.fputcsv-changelog)
- [3v4l results](https://3v4l.org/j4hi0)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use escape character for both fgetcsv() and fputcsv():

```
$objRow = array (
  'general_info' => 'Affordable Dentist."',
  'regular_hours' => 'Mon - Thu: 8:00 am - 5:00 pm Fri: 8:00 am - 1:00 pm Sat - Sun Closed',
  'extra_phones' => '',
  'services_products' => '',
  'payment' => 'amex, cash, check, diners club, discover',
);

$csvHandle = fopen('test.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($csvHandle, $objRow, ',', '"', '\\');
fclose($csvHandle);

$csvHandle = fopen('test.csv', 'r');
$row = fgetcsv($csvHandle, null, ',', '"', '\\');
print_r($row);
```

Comment: It worked but a new issue was found when I changed the escape char to '\\', values with `\\` at the end are not being parsed correctly. Please see the updated question.